# WooCommerce wc_get_product returns False?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use `wc_get_product` function to update the product's price. I hardcoded the ID 80 to see if it works but it probably returns `false`.

I don't understand why since I can clearly see that my first product has ID = 80.

I use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

and this is the code:

```
$product = wc_get_product( 80 );
$product->set_sale_price( 100 );
$product->set_price( 100 );
$product->save();
```

Can you tell me where is the problem? I get this error:

```
Na řádku č. 2 v souboru /data/a/7/a7833039-4699-4c19-96a3-4e99cb97fa3f/premi.cz/web/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(446) : eval()'d code došlo k chybě typu E_ERROR. Chybová zpráva: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function set_sale_price() on bool in /data/a/7/a7833039-4699-4c19-96a3-4e99/premi.cz/web/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(446) : eval()'d code:2
Stack trace:
#0 /data/a/7/a7833039-4699-4c19-96a3-4e99cb97fa3f/premi.cz/web/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(446): eval()
#1 /data/a/7/a7833039-4699-4c19-96a3-4e99cb97fa3f/premi.cz/web/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(534): execute_snippet('$product = wc_g...', 6)
#2 /data/a/7/a7833039-4699-4c19-96a3-4e99cb97fa3f/premi.cz/web/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): execute_active_snippets('')
#3 /data/a/7/a7833039-4699-4c19-96a3-4e99cb97fa3f/premi.cz/web/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#4 /data/a/7/a7833039-4699-4c19-96a3-4e99cb97fa3f/premi.cz/web/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#5 /data/a/7/a7833039-4699-4c19-96a3-4e99cb97fa3f/premi.cz/web/wp-sett
```

Comment: The function `wc_get_product` return `false`

Comment: if it's was object your code will be work

Answer (score 2):

I am facing same problem. I know it's too late for answer this questoin and Also you found a solution for it. But I am going to answer because it's helpful for other user also.

I found the good and working solution. Just create the WooCommerce product factory object and get the product through it. Then after, You able to change the product price like.

```
$productId = 80;
 $_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();
 $product = $_pf->get_product( $productId );

 $product->set_price( 100);
 $product->set_regular_price( 100 );
 $product->set_sale_price( 100 );
 $product->save();
```

It's works for me. I hope this helpful for other people also. If you need more detail about it Then Just follow [this TryVary tutorial](https://tryvary.com/how-to-change-product-price-on-wordpress-woocommerce/#h-change-product-price-programmatically).